# How to collect all README files and rename them in a folder?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, find, xargs

For example, I have these files:

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/etc/images/custom/README
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/etc/images/ezimage/README
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/etc/images/gnus/README
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/etc/images/gud/README
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/etc/images/icons/README
```

I want to collect all of them and save them with different names in one directory, so they become something like this:

```
/dest/custom_README
/dest/ezimage_README
/dest/gnus_README
/dest/gud_README
/dest/icons_README
```

I know `find` and `xargs` might be useful to do this job but don't know how to do the `rename` step according to its directory name.

Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/etc/images -name README |
while IFS= read -r filename; do
    cp -v "$filename" /dest/"$(basename "$(dirname "$filename")")_README"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
[cnicutar@fresh ~]$ sed -r <file 's|.*images/(.*)/(.*)|\1_\2|g'
custom_README
ezimage_README
gnus_README
gud_README
icons_README
```

Or using `awk`:

```
awk < file -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)"_"$NF}'
```